# When I do "npm run", EACCES error shows after the website loads for around 1-2 seconds

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

When I do "npm run web" in my react native app, it shows a EACCES error, which worked just fine the day before.How can I fix this? I searched some other methods but they don't work for my case.

```
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat 
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError 
    at Walker.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:210:21) {
  errno: -4092,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'lstat',
}

Node.js v18.17.1
```

I want to fix this problem

Comment: what os are you using? Have you tried starting as a sudo user, try `sudo npm run web`, that's what I do when I get this type of access error

Comment: I am running it in windows. The program is running in my linux subsystem but not in windows right now

Comment: so yeah, just check to see how to run sudo command on it, hopefully it resolves your issue